# Sending through Postfix fails from a new server. Any troubleshooting suggestions?

Tags: email, postfix, smtp

**Background**
My organization sends list emails from the Mailpoet plugin in Wordpress, hosted on a Linode VPS.

We have a second VPS with Postfix installed, which is used as the SMTP server for Mailpoet's list sends. (This is running Debian GNU/Linux 4.0r9)

We're preparing to move the Wordpress site to a new host (Kinsta).

**Problem**
While testing, we've determined that Mailpoet can't send through the Postfix SMTP server from the Kinsta install.

I'm unfamiliar with Postfix, but reading the documentation it seems that the `mynetworks` configuration variable should set which IPs are allowed to send (or relay) through Postfix. I have added the Kinsta IPs to that list, and confirmed with `postconf` that the configuration was updated.

The Kinsta IPs are not showing up in the Postfix `mail.err` or `mail.warn` logs.

As far as I've been able to tell there is not a firewall running on the VPS (but I'm suspicious that the connection might be getting blocked somewhere other than by Postfix).

If it would be useful, I can post the Postfix configuration here.

**Questions**
I haven't found a good way of troubleshooting this. How would you go about determining why the Postfix connection isn't being accepted?

Do you know of other places, besides the `mynetworks` value, where the new IP would need to be added to Postfix?

I have no documentation about the setup of the VPS. What would you recommend looking at to determine if the connections from Kinsta's server are being prevented somewhere else in the system?

Thanks for your help!

Edit: here is the contents of /etc/postfix/main.cf:

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version

#needed for backscatter prevention
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = yes

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

myhostname = mail.ic.org
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = localhost, 74.50.52.128
#mydestination = ic.org, mail.ic.org, localhost,74.50.52.128

#Mailman config lines
relay_domains = ic.org, lists.ic.org
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
mailman_destination_recipient_limit = 1

# 15MB maximum message size
message_size_limit = 25000000
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8, 65.216.227.186,216.145.134.0/24, 72.249.39.3, 35.245.151.137, 35.230.170.90
# Added Kinsta 35.245.151.137 and 35.230.170.90 IPs 2020-06-30

mailbox_command = procmail
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
home_mailbox = Maildir/
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual

smtpd_sasl_local_domain =
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes

## Use the ordb.org Real Time Black Hole list
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/whitelist, reject_rbl_client sbl-xbl.spamhaus.org, permit
## Don't accept email when the email address used isn't a real domain
smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_unknown_sender_domain

default_rbl_reply = $rbl_code Service unavailable; Your message has been blocked because your server is listed in spamhaus (see http://www.spamhaus.org/faq/)


#smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes

#turned these off 8/30/07
#smtp_use_tls = yes
#smtpd_use_tls = yes

#smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/tls/smtpd.key
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/tls/smtpd.crt
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/postfix/tls/cacert.pem

smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = SSLv3, TLSv1
smtpd_tls_mandatory_ciphers = medium, high


smtpd_tls_loglevel = 3
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom


fork_delay = 5s

default_process_limit = 50

maximal_queue_lifetime = 3d


content_filter = amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
receive_override_options = no_address_mappings
qmgr_message_active_limit = 200
queue_run_delay = 2000s
maximal_backoff_time = 8000s
minimal_backoff_time = 2000s

smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes

smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
    permit_sasl_authenticated,
    permit_mynetworks,
    reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination
```

Edit: the output of the mail.info log file covering the time while a message send from the Kinsta server is being attempted looks like:

```
Jul  1 15:07:25 mail postfix/smtpd[10655]: warning: unknown[185.143.72.25]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: authentication failure
Jul  1 15:07:25 mail postfix/smtpd[13838]: warning: unknown[185.143.73.58]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: authentication failure
Jul  1 15:07:25 mail postfix/smtpd[10541]: connect from unknown[212.70.149.2]
Jul  1 15:07:25 mail postfix/smtpd[10431]: disconnect from unknown[185.143.73.162]
Jul  1 15:07:26 mail postfix/smtpd[13838]: disconnect from unknown[185.143.73.58]
Jul  1 15:07:26 mail postfix/smtpd[10655]: disconnect from unknown[185.143.72.25]
Jul  1 15:07:27 mail postfix/smtpd[10400]: connect from unknown[46.38.150.47]
Jul  1 15:07:27 mail postfix/smtpd[10648]: connect from unknown[185.143.72.16]
Jul  1 15:07:30 mail postfix/smtpd[13838]: connect from unknown[212.70.149.2]
Jul  1 15:07:31 mail postfix/smtpd[10400]: warning: unknown[46.38.150.47]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: authentication failure
Jul  1 15:07:32 mail postfix/smtpd[10541]: warning: unknown[212.70.149.2]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: authentication failure
Jul  1 15:07:32 mail postfix/smtpd[10655]: connect from unknown[212.70.149.50]
Jul  1 15:07:32 mail postfix/smtpd[10400]: disconnect from unknown[46.38.150.47]
Jul  1 15:07:33 mail postfix/smtpd[10648]: warning: unknown[185.143.72.16]: SASL LOGIN
```

The Kinsta IPs don't appear in the log.

This is the log output covering a successful test mail send from the current (linode) server:

```
Jul  1 15:18:04 mail postfix/smtpd[15020]: connect from li1258-185.members.linode.com[45.79.159.185]
Jul  1 15:18:04 mail postfix/smtpd[15803]: warning: unknown[185.143.73.175]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: authentication failure
Jul  1 15:18:05 mail postfix/smtpd[14820]: warning: unknown[141.98.10.192]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: authentication failure
Jul  1 15:18:05 mail postfix/smtpd[14820]: disconnect from unknown[141.98.10.192]
Jul  1 15:18:05 mail postfix/smtpd[15466]: warning: unknown[185.143.73.93]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: authentication failure
Jul  1 15:18:05 mail postfix/smtpd[15020]: 7146B139516: client=li1258-185.members.linode.com[45.79.159.185], sasl_method=LOGIN, sasl_username=noreply
Jul  1 15:18:05 mail postfix/smtpd[15802]: connect from unknown[185.143.73.58]
Jul  1 15:18:05 mail postfix/cleanup[16040]: 7146B139516: message-id=<7335e34f2227a9a8075eeea307bac260@www.ic.org>
Jul  1 15:18:05 mail postfix/smtpd[15466]: disconnect from unknown[185.143.73.93]
Jul  1 15:18:05 mail postfix/smtpd[15803]: disconnect from unknown[185.143.73.175]
Jul  1 15:18:05 mail postfix/smtpd[15020]: disconnect from li1258-185.members.linode.com[45.79.159.185]
Jul  1 15:18:06 mail postfix/smtpd[15461]: connect from unknown[185.143.73.148]
Jul  1 15:18:07 mail postfix/smtpd[15019]: warning: unknown[212.70.149.82]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: authentication failure
Jul  1 15:18:07 mail postfix/smtpd[14030]: warning: unknown[46.38.150.72]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: authentication failure
Jul  1 15:18:07 mail postfix/smtpd[14030]: disconnect from unknown[46.38.150.72]
Jul  1 15:18:07 mail postfix/smtpd[15019]: disconnect from unknown[212.70.149.82]
Jul  1 15:18:07 mail postfix/qmgr[6066]: 7146B139516: from=<noreply@ic.org>, size=1079, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
```

Comment: please show logs and configuration files, otherwise troubleshooting is impossible

Comment: I've added the Postfix config. @natxo-asenjo what from the log files should I post here that would help with troubleshooting? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @MichaelHampton what should I look for in the logs?

Comment: @MichaelHampton what should I look for in the logs to find this? I'm afraid I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "results". I will try tail-ing the mail.info log while attempting to send and see if that yields any information.

Comment: I've added the mail.info log output to the question. The Kinsta IPs don't appear in the log. Any other suggestions about where I should look for clues about what's going on?

Comment: It looks like the client isn't even connecting to your server. You should go check its logs.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @MichaelHampton. I think you're right. Testing reveals that the stream_socket_client() function that Mailpoet's using to connect to the SMTP server works on other arbitrary servers, but not on the Kinsta site. So the issue is probably not related to Postfix at all. I'll post another update when I have more info.

Answer (score 0):

With tips from @MichaelHampton, I eventually realized that the issue was not related to Postfix at all.

Mailpoet uses PHP's `stream_socket_client()` function to connect to the remote SMTP server. I made a test script that used this function and the same parameters, and tried it from the Kinsta server, and from two other arbitrary servers. The other servers connected fine, and the Kinsta server timed out.

After a lengthy chat with Kinsta support, it became clear that Google Cloud's infrastructure that Kinsta runs on prohibits all outbound connections to port 25.

So, the eventual solution was to edit Postfix's master.cf file to allow connections on port 587, and then use that port in Mailpoet.

Thanks for the clues that lead to this solution.